# Firefox css border-width on td element

Tags: css, firefox, html-table

I can't get the border width to be 3px solid green in firefox, even though it is working in Chrome.  How can I fix this?  My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
        <head>
                <style>
                           td {border: 3px solid green; background:blue;}
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <table>
                        <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
        </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: it's working - http://jsfiddle.net/avcfp/

Comment: Thanks, the border collapse is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the spaces and avoid double borders between the cells you have to collapse them, like:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/avcfp/1/)

Also it's a good idea to use some kind of CSS discrepancy eliminator, which can save you a lot of time and helps avoid situations like this - [***Normalize CSS***](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) or [***CSS Reset***](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jw5Gg/1/) i added padding to give it some space. but really it had the border you just needed content. i hope this helped.